# iOS 13 - Using BGTaskScheduler doesn't work all the time

Tags: ios, swift, scheduled-tasks, background-task, ios-background-mode

**THE PROBLEM:**
I want to run a simple function, 5 seconds after app goes into background.

I had to implement [BGTaskScheduler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgtaskscheduler), to support iOS 13.
The old implementation for BackgroundTask works for me on older iOS versions.

I added background modes as requested (BLE accessories is ticked because we perform a small BLE operation in this function):

[image]

Then, I prepared the Info.plist according to the docs (**Identifier is fake** just for StackOverflow question):

[image]

Before **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** is ended, I register my BackgroundTask:

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: "com.example.MyID", using: .global()) { (task) in
            print("My backgroundTask is executed NOW!")
            task.expirationHandler = {
                task.setTaskCompleted(success: true)
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, when the app run the **didEnterBackground** method, I submit a BackgroundTaskRequest:

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            do {
                let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: "com.example.MyID")
                request.earliestBeginDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: 5, to: Date())
                try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)

                print("Submitted task request")
            } catch {
                print("Failed to submit BGTask")
            }
        }
```

The problem here is that it is VERY inconsistent. Apple guarantee that the task will not be executed before the given date, but does not guarantee that it will be executed on the exact time (I'm fine with a small delay).
However, when I ran the app, it did not work 100% of the times, regardless if I provided the task request a delay (using earliestBeginDate) so it used to go first try 7 seconds (instead of 5), next time I submitted the task it took 26 seconds, third time **never** arrived the closure.

Am I implementing the BackgroundTask the wrong way? I've searched all over the internet some answer but did not encounter anyone having this problem.

Comment: The task will be executed only when the system decides to do so. It can execute when the device is charging, etc. As you said the exact success can’t be guaranteed. Watch WWDC 2019 session # 707 for more info.

Comment: @badhanganesh, Thank you for the quick response. Do you have a solution to run a function after X seconds (not minutes..) after going into background? iOS 13.

Comment: Use an application background task. That gives you 30 seconds of extra time.

Comment: @matt I used it, it doesn't seem to work exactly every time I used it, can you post an answer with implementation for using a 5 seconds timer? I tried as Apple docs say.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As badhanganesh said, It seems like the task will be executed only when the system decides to do so.
Apple said that during [WWWDC 2019, session #707](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/707/).

Comment: @mykolaj, I believe there is probably some way to do it, that's probably why people downvoted. I stopped working on it since product definition changed and I had no time to put effort on solving it.

Comment: No. I think people are downvoting because they knows this thing. And you are 100% correct that system will decide. there is no other way to do it in BGTaskSchedular

Answer (score -1):

This was my case too, i found out that in device settings if you go to General-> Background App Refresh is set to “WLAN” and when i switched it to WLAN & MOBILE - my tasks started to execute)) not so frequently as i asked but STILL it worked (mb it can help someone)